# Referenced Libraries ANDROID eclipse

Tags: android, addition, libraries, buildpath

I have problems when I want to add external libraries. I have tried several options.

I pasted the files .jar in the libs folder and then I added them to the build path. The referenced library doesn't create.

do you know what it happens? and how can i create the referenced libraries folder?

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using eclips or android studio? 
. See this 
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download i think it help you.

Comment: thanks, I read it but I continue with the same error, I can't generate Referenced Libraries anyone know why? it's my eclipse version?